# Sql Syntax error in query string with JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to search a table in sql by timestamp using java and jdbc, but when I insert the timestamp into the query string I get a sytax error at the hour figure:

```
 String queryString = "select " + tag +  " from WATER_RUNTIME_VALUES
 where Time_Stamp = 2015-06-150 8:58:00.0000000";

 ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
```

And here is the error:

> **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
>   '10'.**   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:616)
>     at bandon.scada.core.InitConn.calculateHourlyTotal(InitConn.java:58)
>     at bandon.scada.core.InitConn.dbConnect(InitConn.java:36)   at
>   bandon.scada.core.InitConn.main(InitConn.java:24)

Comment: What is the content of tag?

Comment: Consider using parameterized queries.  That will avoid the need to put date literals in quotes and format date literal strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
String queryString = "select ' " + tag + " ' from WATER_RUNTIME_VALUES where Time_Stamp = '2015-06-150 8:58:00.0000000'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Put single quotes in time value to escape the spaces in `2015-06-150 8:58:00.0000000`

```
String queryString = "select " + tag + " from WATER_RUNTIME_VALUES where Time_Stamp = '2015-06-150 8:58:00.0000000'";
```

Or better use `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes in date parameters,

```
String queryString = "select " + tag + " from WATER_RUNTIME_VALUES where Time_Stamp = '2015-06-150 8:58:00.0000000'"
```

Answer (score -1):

The date needs to be within quote marks